# how to recover MBR after Ubuntu installation, how to go back to windows MBR

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, mbr

I'm a new Ubuntu user and have big problem. I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on company laptop. During installation I rewrite mbr on sd1 widdows7 disk. My Grub do not find  windows partition and this partitions looks encrypted. I forgot that all physical disks are encrypted. Do you know how to recover MBR after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Your company's laptop is not for you to fiddle with. In my company that is enough for termination and the courts agree. That said, you should always have Windows Media (installation or recovery) to boot from a fix such situations.

Comment: Once i used a tool called as mini tool partition wizard in bootable format and there it had a option to rebuild MBR...aomei assistant in bootable form also has it...try it